# Copy multiple sheets to a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

The following code is supposed to copy all worksheets (except last 2) from workbook called PCReport to a new workbook called Insp & date.

It falls over on the line

```
Workbooks(xWkb).Sheets(sheet.Name).Copy after:=Workbooks(tgtWkb).Sheets(x)
```

The error is runtime error 424, object required.

x = 1, total = 10, xWkb = "PCReport.xlsm", tgtWkb = "Insp25112015.xls"

```
Dim total As Integer
Dim NewWkb As Workbook
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xWkb As String
Dim tgtWkb As String
Dim i As Integer

xWkb = "PCReport.xlsm"
Set NewWkb = Workbooks.Add
'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Carol\Desktop\Insp" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Carol.Hedges\Insp" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xls"
tgtWkb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
total = Workbooks(xWkb).Worksheets.Count
i = 1
For x = 1 To total - 2
    Workbooks(xWkb).Sheets(sheet.Name).Copy after:=Workbooks(tgtWkb).Sheets(x)
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: Where the 'x' variable came from, I think you are using variable 'i'?

Comment: What is `sheet` of `sheet.Name` supposed to be? You don't declare it.

Comment: change the line to `Workbooks(xWkb).Sheets(x).Copy after:=Workbooks(tgtWkb).Sheets(x)`. note : using index might be tricky, maybe better loop all sheets and add a condition to avoid the two last sheets by name. Note 2: what is the variable i used for ?, use Option Explicit, some variables aren't declared.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you, you don't need i as Paresh suggested, it might be useful when using while loop but not here:

```
Dim NewWkb As Workbook
Dim xWkb As Workbook
Dim x as Integer

Set xWkb = Workbooks("PCReport.xlsm")
Set NewWkb = Workbooks.Add
NewWkb.SaveAs "C:\Users\Carol.Hedges\Insp" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xls"
For x = 1 To xWkb.Worksheets.Count - 2
    xWkb.Sheets(x).Copy after:=NewWkb.worksheets(NewWkb.worksheets.count)
Next x
```

Comment: Good answer. You still need to declare x as long or integer.

Comment: I edited the answer. But in fact if Option Explicit is not written, the code still works. For bigger projects declaring all variables is necessary to clearly state the scopes of the variables but for one procedure I don't know if the necessity is that strong.